# How to re-blink a div using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that we can use the below css to blink a div for the number of times specified:

html:

```
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
```

css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
0% { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.0; }
100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
0% { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.0; }
100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
.blink {
-webkit-animation: blinker 1s 5;
-moz-animation: blinker 1s 5;
animation: blinker 1s 5;
}
```

By using the css way, the div will blink after the page loaded without us calling any js function.
But then what if i want to re-blink the div after the user press a button? There's no function to call on "onclick".

```
<button onclick="">BLINK AGAIN!</button>
```

Any idea how to do it?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaysf/867/)

Comment: You would need to toggle the class.

Comment: It's quite tricky. Check this: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: The crux of this question is the same as [**this one that I answered yesterday**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347992/reuse-css-animation-in-reversed-direction-by-resetting-the-state/33351228#33351228). You **cannot restart a CSS animation using CSS alone**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the class 'blink' then add it back again, in order to restart the CSS animation

You'll need to use a `setTimeout` so that it doesn't have the class added to it before it has has the class taken away from it

```js
$("#blinkagain").click(function() {
    var $el = $(".blink");
    $el.removeClass("blink");
    setTimeout(function() {$el.addClass("blink");}, 500);
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
.blink {
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1s 5;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1s 5;
  animation: blinker 1s 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
<button id="blinkagain">BLINK AGAIN!</button>
```

Comment: It's not working sir..

Comment: Sorry, I messed up, have a look now @Coolguy