# Repeat css animation with checkbox

Tags: css, animation

Is it possible to run again css animateion without js?

```
@-webkit-keyframes aaa {
  to {
    background: red;
  }
}
input:checked + div {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-name: aaa;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-name: aaa;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

When checkbox is checked i want to run again my animation?

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<div></div>
```

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BovjdN)

Comment: like so? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGexXr

Comment: Please have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347992/reuse-css-animation-in-reversed-direction-by-resetting-the-state/33351228#33351228). Your question is different but the point would be the same. You can't restart an animation with CSS alone.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: I think OP wants the animation to run once on load and then again when the input is checked.

Comment: You can if you [duplicate the `keyframes` block and give it a different name and use that name in the `:checked` rule](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmoXEE) (tested on Chrome). Depending on your use case this may or may not be desirable. The animation then runs when the page loads and on every change of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to solve your issue with just one keyframe declaration.

As [DarkFalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55120502) points out you can solve it by declaring two different `keyframes` and apply one for the `:checked` and the other for the initial state.

#### Code Snippet

```css
@keyframes aaa {
  to {
    background: red;
  }
}
@keyframes bbb {
  to {
    background: red;
  }
}

input:checked + div {
  animation-name: bbb;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:blue;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: aaa;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<div></div>
```

If I find another way around this, where you don't need two declared keyframes I'll update my answer.