# Pure CSS animation-play-state Door Effect Button

Tags: html, css

So basically i wanted to create a kind of door effect with a div

Open and Shut when clicking a button.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
      document.getElementById(target.dataset.target + '-div').className = target.textContent === 'stop' ? '' : target.textContent;
    }
      
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  transform: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0 white solid;
  background-color: green;
}

#transition-div {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#transition-div.start {
  transform: translateX(400px);
}


@keyframes move-right {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  50% { transform: translateX(400px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Transition</h1>
  <button data-target="transition">start</button>
  <button data-target="transition">stop</button>
  <div id="transition-div"></div>
</section>
```

Can the top result be created in pure CSS or does javascript have to be implemented into the webpage?
And are you able to have a 'start' and 'stop' button merged into one single button?
Cheers guys!

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347992/reuse-css-animation-in-reversed-direction-by-resetting-the-state/33351228#33351228 You are looking for something very similar (that is, play the reverse animation on second click or click of second button).

Comment: The above comment is based on assumption that you are trying to do it for an "animated" element. If you are just trying to achieve that effect using CSS then it should be possible to do using transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using CSS only

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  transform: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0 white solid;
  background-color: green;
}
#transition-div {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
#toggleStartStop { display: none }
#toggleStartStop ~ label[for="toggleStartStop"] {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}

#toggleStartStop:checked ~ #transition-div {
  transform: translateX(400px);
}
#toggleStartStop ~ label[for="toggleStartStop"]:after {
  content: 'Start';
}
#toggleStartStop:checked ~ label[for="toggleStartStop"]:after {
  content: 'Stop';
}

@keyframes move-right {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  50% { transform: translateX(400px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Transition</h1>
  <input id="toggleStartStop" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for="toggleStartStop"></label>
  <div id="transition-div"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is only on how to get the exact same output without using JS (and not necessarily use `animation` or `animation-play-state`) then you can do it like in the below snippet. On the other hand if you are trying to get this forward and reverse effect  for an **animation** using CSS, it isn't possible.

Here, an input element and a label (which works as the button) are used. When the label is clicked the `input` gets checked (based on the `for` attribute). If the `input` is checked then the `transform` gets applied to the element using `input:checked ~ #transitiondiv` selector. It means ***select the element which is a sibling of `input`, has `id='transitiondiv'` when the `input` is checked***. When label is clicked again, the `input` gets un-checked, so the element gets toggled back to original state.

To move the `input` itself to be outside viewing area, a `position: absolute` with a negative value for `left` property is used.

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  transform: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0 white solid;
  background-color: green;
}
#transition-div {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:checked ~ #transition-div {
  transform: translateX(400px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="checkbox" id="control" />
  <label for="control">Toggle</label>
  <div id="transition-div"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! very useful :) Would never have thought of using a label and a checkbox
at the start i was trying to do this using the CSS animation but it seems i was going with it in the wrong way
Thank you again!